# Meaning of 'uneingeleiteter Ergänzungssatz'

Tags: sentence-structure, german-to-english, terminology

What is the meaning of *uneingeleiteter Ergänzungssatz*? Does it refer to the use of *dass* in the sentence as a connector of two phrases and positioning the verb at the end?

Comment: Where did you encounter this term? According to Google, it is quite rarely used.

Comment: I am enrolled in A2 Language Course from Goethe Institute in Delhi.
Their content has this word. When I used google translator, it was not showing me the meaning for each word but if I combined them, then I would get the meaning as unaccompanied supplementary sentence, and I got completely confused with this meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ich glaube, dass er recht hat.

*I think that he is right.*

This is a sentence with a main clause and a dependent (here: object) clause introduced by *dass*. The object clause serves as an object to *glauben*.

> Ich glaube, er hat recht.

*I think he is right.*

This is a sentence with a main clause and an *uneingeleiteter Ergänzungssatz* – also a main clause. The meaning is identical to the above sentence with the object clause, though the second clause follows the rules of the main clause.

This kind of *uneingeleiteter Ergänzungssatz* is similar to the structures in English and should be no problem to you. Just mind the comma.

---

However, there is another kind:

> Regnet es, bleibe ich zu Hause.

***If*** it rains I stay at home.

The *if* is implicit. You can spot those *uneingeleiteter Ergänzungssatz* by the finite verb in front though it's not in *Imperativ* mode. *Indikativ* and *Konjunktiv* are possible:

> Hätte ich das gewusst, wäre ich zuhause geblieben.

*If I knew that I stayed at home.*

---

There is a third kind, also with the finite verb in front:

> Er wusste nicht, war das gut oder schlecht.

*He didn't know **whether** that was good or bad.*

Comment: In the examples with conditional V1-clauses (*Regnet es …* and *Hätte ich das gewusst …*), the dependent clauses function as *Angaben*, not *Ergänzungen*.

Comment: All these things are okay. I couldnt understand the third kind and one just above it, as I havent reached upto that level yet. When we say uneingeleiteter Ergänzungen, what does it refer to?

Comment: *Uneingeleitet* means *without an introduction*, because there is no marker word as *dass* or *wenn*. *Ergänzung* means *addition*, so an *Ergänzungssatz* is *a clause with additions*.

Answer (score 1):

Janka's answer is fine, but let's examine the terminology a bit closer.

Let's take care of *Ergänzungssatz* first. [*Ergänzung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erg%C3%A4nzung_(Grammatik)) is the German term for [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)), i.e. subjects and objects; the complementary term is [*Angabe*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angabe_(Grammatik)), English [modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier).

For many verbs, the object may either be a noun phrase or a sentence. In the first case, the German term would be *nominale Ergänzung* (noun phrase complement).

> Die Wissenschaftler untersuchten **das Phänomen** gründlich.
>   The scientists examined **the phenomenon** carefully.

In the second, *Ergänzungssatz* or *Objektsatz* (sentential complement or complement clause).

> Die Wissenschaftler untersuchten gründlich, **ob Pferde zählen können**.
>   The scientists examined carefully **whether horses can count**.

(I threw in *gründlich* in the above examples because it is an example of a modifier or *Angabe*; as is *nicht mehr* below.).

Now for certain verbs, there are two types of *Ergänzungssatz* possible:

> Ich glaube, **daß** sie mich nicht mehr **liebt**.
>   Ich glaube, sie **liebt** mich nicht mehr.
>
> I think (that) she doesn't love me anymore.

How to distinguish them? It appears that there is a tradition that calls the first *eingeleiteter Ergänzungssatz/Objektsatz/Nebensatz*, as it is introduced by the subordinating conjunction *daß*, and the second *uneingeleiteter Ergänzungssatz/Objektsatz/Nebensatz*, as there is no subordinating conjunction.

However, I am not a fan of this terminology. Learners of German are trained to distinguish verb-initial and verb-final clauses from the get-go, so the position of the finite verb should be the most prominent feature. An alternative terminology uses **abhängiger/eingebetteter Verbzweitsatz** (dependent/embedded V2-clause) for the second case, **abhängiger/eingebetteter Verbletztsatz** (dependent/embedded verb-final clause) for the first.

This terminology has the advantage of highlighting the position of the finite verb. However, since *abhängig/eingebettet* is less precise than *Ergänzung/Objekt* , I'd actually prefer **Verbzweitsatz als Objekt/Ergänzung** (V2 complement clause), **Verbletztsatz als Objekt/Ergänzung** (verb-final complement clause).